# mysql select rows if column = x otherwise column = 0, distinct

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I am using MySQL and stuck with - i guess simple issue. It looks like this:

I have a table:

```
-----------------
id | name | age 
-----------------
1  | abc  | 0
2  | cde  | 30
3  | abc  | 30
4  | efg  | 0
```

Now, i want to select name and age but select all of them with upcoming condition:
if there is any row with age 30 select it, otherwise select those with age 0. if there is both 30 and 0 age (like in example above) select only one row with age = 30. if there is only row with age = 0 - select it.

Using table from above i want to have result like this:

```
id | name | age 
-----------------
2  | cde  | 30
3  | abc  | 30
4  | efg  | 0
```

Mysql should ignore first row with age 0 because there is row with the same name but age = 30. 
I tried

```
SELECT name, age FROM table WHERE CASE WHEN age = 30 THEN 1 ELSE age = 0 END
```

But it selects multiple rows with both 0 and 30 age. 
Hope you can help me.

Comment: `select ... group by age`?

Comment: can you provide 4 more additional sample rows with the expected output? not exactly sure what you want still

Comment: do you only want one row that has age of 0 and every row where age is 30?

Comment: i want only rows with age 30 with unique name. if there is no row with distinct name and age 30 then select name and age 0. in other words i want to select only one row for each name, with age 0 only if there is no such names with age 30

Comment: @MarcB group by age would not produce the results the OP wanted.. he needed filtering on age and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but test it and see if it works :)

```
(SELECT id, name, age FROM myTable WHERE age = 30)

UNION

(SELECT id, name, age FROM myTable WHERE age = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f836f/1) to play with

```
(SELECT id, name, age FROM myTable WHERE age = 30)

UNION

(SELECT id, name, age
FROM mytable
WHERE age = 0
  AND name NOT in(SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE age = 30)
ORDER BY id DESC)
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/474694/1) with op requests

Comment: unfortunately your example doesnt work for me. Pls check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05fa5/1/0 - id = 5 shouldnt be in results because there is already row with name = cde and age = 30 (id 2)

Comment: made some changes. it now checks to filter out when the name is equal

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work too - check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d778f/1/0 - it doesnt results 'eeg' row although it has only age 0 :(

Comment: you aren't being clear on what you want. do you want all age 0's to appear that don't have a name match to age 30? from my understanding you wanted just one. do you want the more recent one? or the oldest one? please clarify what you want and be specific.

Comment: @Kalreg ok i just changed it up some. look at it and let me know if that helps. i also updated the answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/474694/1

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted to achieve. thank you very much. +1 for you

Comment: ok cool... sorry it was hard to understand your instructions on it. lol good luck!